# Is a broader term than Neuro-Muscolo-Skeletal used in medical literature?

Tags: terminology, orthopedics

Many Mechanic conditions involving anatomic deformity or idiopathic chronic joint inflammation conditions are classified as Neuro-Muscolo-Skeletal (NMS).

Is there another widely accepted broader term (such as Skeletal-Joint-Tendon-Bone-Neuronal --- SJTBN) in the medical literature?

Comment: I don't see how the example you give is more broad than neuro-musculo-skeletal.

Comment: SJTBN would be redundant, actually. "Skeletal" includes bones, joints, and ligaments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Neuro-musculo-skeletal system** is already a broad term, which includes 3 systems:

- **Nervous system,** which can be further divided to central and peripheral, somatic and autonomic, sensory and motor system
- **Muscular system,** which includes skeletal muscles with the associated tendons (which you can control consciously), smooth muscles (which you cannot control consciously) and the heart muscle
- **Skeletal system,** which includes bones, joints and ligaments (which connect the bones)

The names of complex systems include only the "main" systems (like the bold ones above) that are on the same level and not the smaller parts of every included system.

To clear some confusion:

A *tendon* is a part of a muscle that connects the muscle to a bone, so it is a part of *muscular* system. It is usually said: a tendon of (the muscle), for example, [long tendon of the biceps brachii](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8665288).

A *ligament* is a band of connective tissue that is not a part of a muscle or bone, but it connects bones, so it is usually considered a part of *skeletal* system ([Biology Libre Texts](https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Human_Biology/Book%3A_Human_Biology_(Wakim_and_Grewal)/14%3A_Skeletal_System/14.2%3A_Introduction_to_the_Skeletal_System), [Ontology Lookup Service](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies/uberon/terms?iri=http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FUBERON_0008846)).

The main medical specialties that deal with the above systems include:

- Neurology
- Orthopedy (mechanical aspect)
- Rheumatology (inflammatory aspect)
- Traumatology (injuries)
- Occupational medicine
- Sports medicine
- Physical medicine and rehabilitation (exercises to overcome disabilities, surgery, stroke or injuries)

Comment: Are tendons considered part of the muscular system or skeletal? With no supporting references that's not clear.

Comment: I explained that in the answer now.